# Changed iPhone App Target Name, now app "Finished Running"

Tags: iphone, ios, build, settings, target

I made one very innocent change to my app: I changed the name of the target by clicking on the icon itself in the menu tray and changing its name there (I changed it to "Subject", on the odd chance that matters). After that, the app has not run on the device or in the simulator any more.

On the device, it says build successful, then it says "Finished running Appname on iPhone 4S" (where Appname is the name of my app, which I might as well keep top secret).

On the simulator, it stalls at "Attaching to Appname.Appname"

In a panic, I changed the name back to the original one, and the problem persists.

Please note that I did not manually change anything in the settings, just changed the icon name itself. The settings automatically replaced $(TARGET_NAME) with the new name, and now they automatically replace it with the old name again.

Also, please do not mark this as a duplicate of other "finished running" questions, as I have specified the exact change I made before encountering the problem, and none of the previous posts seem to deal with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

> - Product -> Clean.
> - Delete apps on Simulator & device.
> - Restart Xcode.

Comment: Tried that. To get things going again, I ended up making a new project with the same app name as the original and importing all the files. Still wish I understood what really went wrong, but problem solved nonetheless.

Comment: And I'll accept your answer, since you were nice enough to offer a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

After renaming some files in my project I added them again to my project. I added a file info.plist that doesn't belongs to the project (I think!). After that the simulator start and doesn't work. The message "finished running..." appears in Xcode. After I tried again, the simulator work. So every time I need to simulate the application I needed to run twice for this to work.

After extensively looking I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I deleted the info.plist and the program run well now as before. That was the solution for my problem. Please, make a back-up of info.plist before doing that.
Try to restore a back-up of info.plist whom worked and add to the project.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the new target had the same Bundle Identifier of the old one. Hope it helps!